# My search field become very big and website's comment becomes smaller as I scale width

Tags: html, css

Here is the source code and seems like there is no mistake, but maybe I got an error in CSS. I wanted to learn how to create an adaptive website and followed the instructions in the video linked below, but it still goes wrong. I hope that some of web development professionals or advanced will help me or at least show me the error.

CSS:

```
body {
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}
header{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
header li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left:15px;
}
header a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.header-wrap{
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
input{
  margin-top: 10px;
}
main{
  display: flex;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
section{
  width: 70%;
}
aside{
  width: 30%;
}
.post-itm{
  display:inline-block;
  width: 23%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px){
  .post-itm{
    width: 30%;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>My first responsive website!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="header-wrap">
                <nav>
                    <ul class="main-nav">
                        <li class="nav-itm"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-itm"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-itm"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <input type="search">
            </div>
        </header>
        <main>
            <section>
                <article class="post">
                    <h1>New Post</h1>
                    <div class="post-itm"><img src="images/pixel-icon-tumblr-20.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="post-itm"><img src="images/pixel-icon-tumblr-20.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="post-itm"><img src="images/pixel-icon-tumblr-20.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="post-itm"><img src="images/pixel-icon-tumblr-20.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="post-itm"><img src="images/pixel-icon-tumblr-20.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="post-itm"><img src="images/pixel-icon-tumblr-20.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="post-itm"><img src="images/pixel-icon-tumblr-20.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="post-itm"><img src="images/pixel-icon-tumblr-20.jpg"></div>
                </article>
            </section>
            <aside>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">About</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Rem tempore vero ab natus laudantium At voluptas incidunt sed rerum nihil ut quae enim. 
                    Sit possimus molestiae et minus commodi ad obcaecati enim sit explicabo vero. 
                    Qui blanditiis debitis At ratione beatae nam perspiciatis quod ea sint tenetur eos nihil optio. 
                    A voluptatibus consequatur et placeat rerum et deleniti cupiditate ut consequatur amet et ducimus quia sit magnam error eos magni aliquam.
                </p>
            </aside>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

I was trying to create adaptive website and as soon as I used `justify-content: space-between` property on, the search field grow and it doesnt work as it was shown in the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-xc1EOMOIE&ab_channel=WebDeveloperBlog)

Comment: The Flex function is quite complex for beginners. In general, of course, it makes sense to understand the structure of websites. But today it is hardly worth to build a layout by yourself, because it costs too much time and does not work the same on all devices. (Except with even more work.) Therefore my tip: Familiarize yourself with a CSS framework like Bootstrap 5. With it you can build fast nice solid basic frameworks and also use nice features like an accordion or pop-up boxes. You just have to load the CSS and JS files in the <head> and off you go.